# Put where clause criteria in SQL based on conditions?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a stored procedure with two parameters which is returning me the list of employees. My stored procedure is working fine but I need to put criteria in my where clause based on conditions. Following is my stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_GetEmployees

   @BranchId int = 0,
   @DeptId int = 0

as

Begin

 if(@BranchId > 0 and @DeptId > 0)
  select * from Employees where BranchId = @BranchId and DeptId = @DeptId
 else if (@BranchId > 0 and @DeptId = 0)
  select * from Employees where BranchId = @BranchId
 else if (@BranchId > 0 and @DeptId = 0)
  select * from Employees where DeptId = @DeptId
 else
  select * from Employees

End
```

This is simple case but I have more complex scenarios where I am passing 8 to 10 parameters and making conditions for them will be big headache. I need to simplify it in one select statement. I tried the following but of course, it is not correct:

```
if(@BranchId > 0 or @DeptId > 0)
select * from Employees where
     case @BranchId when 0 then ''
     else BranchId = @BranchId 
     End
else
select * from Employees
```

How can I simplify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query like following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Employee 
WHERE  ( Branchid = @BranchId 
          OR @BranchId = 0 ) 
       AND ( Deptid = @DeptId 
              OR @DeptId = 0 )
```

Comment: What this `OR @BranchId = 0` doing?

Comment: If 0 then consider all branches

Comment: Can I do same thing for date as well?  e.g. `where  ( EmployeeJoiningDate >= @Date OR @Date = null)` if date is null ?

Comment: @ArmaanLabib you can't use logical operators against a `NULL`. `NULL = NULL` returns "unknown", which is **not** true. You have to use `IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: So it should be like this: `( EmployeeJoiningDate >= @Date OR @Date is null) `

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this, adding the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your query; this means that any Cached query plans won't be used, as they could be useless to a different set of parameters (with this being a catch-all query):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetEmployees @BranchId int = 0,
                                 @DeptId int = 0
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM Employees
    WHERE (BranchId = @BranchId
        OR @BranchId = 0)
      AND (DeptId = @DeptId
        OR @DeptId = 0)
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);

END;
```

You were trying to use the `CASE` **expression** like a statement, which is it not.

Comment: If '0' its mean I have to show all the records not where `BranchId = 0`

Comment: What this  `OR @BranchId = 0` doing?

Comment: @ArmaanLabib that is exactly what that query is doing. Not sure how to describe what `OR @BranchId = 0` as a `OR` clause is one of the most simple things in SQL. `(BranchId = @BranchId OR @BranchId = 0)` is effectively saying "Return rows where the value of `BranchID` and `@BranchID` are the same, or rows where `@BranchID` (Your parameter) is `0`." So, if `@BranchID = 0` that will evaluate to true for every row.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
WHERE (@Parameter1 = 0 OR Field1=@Parameter1)
AND (@Parameter2 = 0 OR Field2=@Parameter2)
AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your query with condition check like this way :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Your stored procedure name]  
 @aaa  INT condition parameter,  
 @bbb INT condition parameter,  
 @ccc INT condition parameter,  
 @RecordCount INT OUTPUT   
AS   

Declare @aaa nvarchar(500)  
Declare @bbb nvarchar(500)  
Declare @ccc nvarchar(500)  
BEGIN  
 BEGIN TRY  

  SET @qry = N'SELECT <here your query> where  1=1  
     '  
  IF @aaa= 0  
  BEGIN  
   SET @aaa = ''  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
   SET @aaa = ' and p.userid = '+CONVERT(varchar(5),@aaa)+' '  
  END  

  IF @bbb= 0  
  BEGIN  
   SET @bbb = ''  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
   SET @bbb = ' and p.Senderid = '+CONVERT(varchar(10),@bbb)+' '  
  END
```

Comment: This way of writing is open to injection, you should be parametrising dynamic statements.

Comment: @Larnu how are they written

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that comment Gajjar, seems like it's an incomplete sentance.

Comment: I mean you can put your parametrising dynamic statements as answer

Comment: This doesn't need dynamic SQL Gajjar, in my opinion. Boolean logic (with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`) would work fine here.